# Place div below another div with property display:grid

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, css-grid

I'm having issues trying to put a div below another div with diplay:grid. The div is being placed on top of the other one and not below.

"app-bm-payment-card-item" is a custom Angular component.

HTML file

```
//div wrapper
<div *ngIf="pageReady && myProfiles" class="ion-padding">

//div showing the cards stacked or collapsed
<div *ngIf="!inEditMode" class="card_container_stacked_main">
  <app-bm-payment-card-item *ngFor="let card of myProfiles" [card]="card" [editMode]="inEditMode"
    (onDeleteClick)="removeCard(card)" (onSelect)="selectCard(card)" (onEditClick)="editCardInfo(card)">
  </app-bm-payment-card-item>
</div>

//div showing the cards expanded
<div *ngIf="inEditMode" class="card_container_expanded_main">
  <app-bm-payment-card-item *ngFor="let card of myProfiles" [card]="card" [editMode]="inEditMode"
    (onDeleteClick)="removeCard(card)" (onSelect)="selectCard(card)" (onEditClick)="editCardInfo(card)">
  </app-bm-payment-card-item>
</div>

//div to be placed below the other one(s)
<div class="div">
  TEXT
</div>

</div>
```

SCSS file:

```
.card_container_stacked_main {
display:grid;
position: relative;
grid-auto-rows:30px; /* a fixed height to create an overflow */ 
}

.card_container_expanded_main {
position: relative;
max-width: 400px !important;
//margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.div {
position: relative;
}
```

So, the basic functionality is when tapping on any card the card list should be display stacked or collapsed. That's why I'm using the inEditMode boolean, to get to know which div should be displayed and which one hidden. When the expanded card list is displayed the div (TEXT) is being placed below the list correctly, but when the stacked card list is activated the div is being placed on top of the list, which is wrong, it should be placed below the stacked/collapsed card list. See the images below.

[image: Stacked card list]

[image: Collapsed card list]

Comment: How many stack column item you want to show?

Comment: Do you mean how many cards stacked?, if so, it’s a dynamic value. The problem is related to the grid, because the div (TEXT) is acting like it is another card stacked, it should be place below the stacked cards because it’s another div..right?

Comment: So you actual want to show text below grid? And stack grid is fine for you.

Comment: I want the div TEXT to stay below the stacked grid, just like the second image in which the div TEXT is placed right below the expanded card list.

Comment: I have sent you mail. Please check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting problem, because the number of cards in the "wallet" can be 1, 2 or `N` and the fact that `grid-auto-rows` and/or `grid-template-rows` need to have *tracking size* explicit specified in the CSS.

### Multiple solutions available (conserving the use of grid)

[image][image]

#### #1 The easy but ugly one

Simply set a `margin-top: 200px;` to the TEXT div. You apply this only when the cards are stacked.

I'm not a big fan of this solution since is more a "fix" than a proper design.

```js
function expandStackCards() {
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  if (wrapper.classList.contains("stacked")) {
    wrapper.classList.remove("stacked");
  } else {
    wrapper.classList.add("stacked");
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px;
  gap: 10px;
}
#wrapper.stacked  {
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
  gap: 0px;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
.card.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.card.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.my-text {
  margin: 10px;
}
.stacked .my-text {
  margin-top: 200px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="expandStackCards()">Expand / Stack</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="stacked">
  <div class="card green"><span>Card #1</span></div>
  <div class="card blue"><span>Card #2</span></div>
  <div class="my-text">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Or find [here the Codepen code](https://codepen.io/BSO__/pen/qBPpvqp)

#### #2 Using JavaScript to detect and set properly the `grid-auto-rows` value

In my opinion the best solution since there is no `margin` trick, only pur grid CSS.

To achieve that you need a bit of JS to detect the number of cards in the wallet, then set the value.

```js
function stackedCards() {
  var wrapper = document.querySelector('#wrapper.stacked');
  if (wrapper) {
    var num_cards = wrapper.querySelectorAll(':scope .card').length;

    let style = getComputedStyle(wrapper);
    row_height_str = style.gridAutoRows;

    var new_grid_auto_rows = row_height_str.concat(' ').repeat(num_cards - 1);

    new_grid_auto_rows = new_grid_auto_rows.concat('auto');

    wrapper.style.gridAutoRows = new_grid_auto_rows;
  }
}

// This function is only for the DEMO button
function expandStackCards() {
  var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
  if (wrapper.classList.contains("stacked")) {
    wrapper.classList.remove("stacked");
    wrapper.style.removeProperty("grid-auto-rows");
  } else {
    wrapper.classList.add("stacked");
    stackedCards();
  }
}

stackedCards();
```

```css
button {
  width: 400px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 400px;
  gap: 10px;
}
#wrapper.stacked {
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
  gap: 0px;
}
.card {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card span {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
}
.card.green {
  background-color: green;
}
.card.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.my-text {
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="expandStackCards()">Expand / Stack</button>
<div id="wrapper" class="stacked">
  <div class="card green"><span>Card #1</span></div>
  <div class="card blue"><span>Card #2</span></div>
  <div class="my-text">TEXT</div>
</div>
```

Or find [here the Codepen code](https://codepen.io/BSO__/pen/WNZdPXY)

#### #3 Using JavaScript to set a class to the `#wrapper`

You can also use JS to detect the number of cards, then apply the right class to the grid (`#wrapper`).

It's a bit like the previous solution but without applying CSS style via JS, but of course for this you will need to have in your CSS file something like that :

```
.wallet-1-cards {
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}
.wallet-2-cards {
  grid-auto-rows: 30px auto;
}
.wallet-3-cards {
  grid-auto-rows: 30px 30px auto;
}
.wallet-4-cards {
  grid-auto-rows: 30px 30px 30px auto;
}

// etc...
```

With this third solution you avoid doing CSS in your JS code (you only set a class to a div), which is not a bad solution only if you know that it's impossible to have more that like 5 or 6 cards, because polluting your CSS with dozens of useless definitions is not a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

This should move the text under the last card. I tested it and worked for me:

Set property stackedContainerHeight or something like that and calculate container height ->

> stackedContainerHeight = height of a stacked card in pixels * (lenght of card/profile array -1) + full card height + adjustments like margins etc.

For example:

```
stackedContainerHeight = 30 * (this.myProfiles.length-1) + 50 +15;
```

Set the stacked container height dynamically for the container element

```
[style.height.px]="stackedContainerHeight"
```

What is the original problem: Grid-auto-rows cuts the container height and part of the last full card flow over the container. This solution calculates the right height and text div will be rendered aftr the container correctly.